# How to save a String JSON element on multiple folders

Tags: java, json, java.nio.file

I have a JSON file with 70 objects, each object contain elements such as arrays. Here is an example of JSON object:

```
{ 
   "journal": ".....",
   "category": ["Sport", "football", "Real Madrid"],
   "abstract": "Here is an example"
}
```

First, I create folders with Strings of the element `"category"`. The next step is to create a `.txt` file from the string of the element `"abstract"`. What I would to do is save each `.txt` file on these folders.

For instance, the element `"abstract"` contains string "Here is an example", I create a `.txt` file with this phrase and I want to know how do I save it on folder `Sport`, `Football` and `Real Madrid`.

Comment: What did you try so far? Your problem refers to extracting `JSONArray` contents or creating directories?

Comment: Use the [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) class.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou create directories from JSONArray element and save another element in each category created before with JSONArray

Comment: @Robert thank you, how can i use it ? please!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example java:

```
// create a list of folder names and call it "folderArray".
// You are already doing something like this, but I don't know the variable name.
// You also have the name of the abstract text file name in a variable.
// This code assumes that variable is called "abstractFileName".

for (final String folder : folderArray)
{
    final String newFileName = folder + File.separatorChar + abstractFileName;

    // create a file with the name "newFileName"

    // Write the abstract contents to the new file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("category");
File f = new File("C:/Files");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  String folderName = arr.getString(i);
  File folder = new File(folderName);
  if(folder.mkdir()) {
    File file = new File(folderName + "fileName.txt");
    String data = obj.getString("abstract");

    // Now using stream write the data to this file
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file));
    dos.writeUTF(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that code create the folders and the text files it's good, but it doesn't affect the texts to the folders created

Comment: how can i save the txt file on all or some the directories created before

Comment: I am not understanding what you really want..Can you  explain it?

Comment: i want to write the txt file in each directory i've created:
I parse each element of JSON, then i get the text and save it in `.txt` i also created directories from a JSONArray Element. Now i want to assign the txt file to each of those categories 
I hope i clarify things @Ashraf Ali